# How to get item sold notification using Amazon Marketplace Web Service (MWS)

Tags: web, service, amazon-mws, marketplace

I want to get item sold notification for items listed on amazon marketplace programmatically. Is there a way to do this using MWS APIs? I looked through the documentation and didn't quite find anything close.

Answer (score 3):

Hi I know that this is old and the user that asked the question is probably inactive.

Though just in case someone lands here I would to say that at the moment of writing this MWS does not support item sold notifications (the might do in the future) for now the only notification supported is "AnyOfferChanged".
[more info](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/subscriptions/MWSSubscriptionsApiReference._V356512412_.pdf)

The way to get the orders will be by making a call to the ListOrders service, more info 
[here](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/orders/MWSOrdersApiReference._V384929319_.pdf)

Hope this helps anyone

Answer (score 0):

You have to use MWS service from Amazon.

You will find all docs, api and information on this website : https://developer.amazonservices.com/.

You have to code the call to their webservice and treat response.

There is an "order" call than you can load, using a cron for example, to get any new orders. This is the [order api call](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/orders/2013-09-01/index.html).

I hope this help.
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the description of `FulfillmentOrderStatus` notification type

https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/subscriptions/Subscriptions_NotificationType.html